# Execute property for oracle pkgs on Unix

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, file-properties

I am trying to understand file properties and from what I understand that for the files like shell scripts on UNIX to be executable, the file properties need to be set to execute (rwx-). At our organization, oracle files are maintained on UNIX file system and compiled on oracle during the time of run or compiled once for all the schemas. But the pkgs maintained on UNIX, some have executable property and some don't(rwxrwxr-- and rw-r--r--). So when a shell script is calling this pkg that is not executable how will it be able to compile on Oracle? Please help me understand or direct me to documents that has notes on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package script itself doesn't need to be executable as it's just a text file containing source code. SQL*Plus reads the contents and submits it to the server for compilation.

Comment: Thanks @William Robertson.